# Logistic regression pulling in variables not included in formula - Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

Now quite sure what's going on here.  Using this code with two independent variables has no issues.  However, when I add a third variable, 'gender_lbl' is the only variable in the output.  Even though 'gender_lbl' is not included in the code.

Is this a common issue?

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit

model14 = logit(formula = 'Vote1 ~ C(race_lbl) * C(party_lbl) * C(age_group)',
           data = db).fit()
model4.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you modify the code to show [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just updated to include the library import and image of the output.  Unsure if anything else would help.  I'm clearly new to coding and Stack Overflow.  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure it possible for others to understand and see the problem. This starts with giving context for the problem you are trying to solve (where does `statsmodels` come from? Have you tried checking its documentation?) and especially involves showing enough code that someone else can copy and paste to reproduce the problem. I have no idea what kind of data is supposed to be used with this code - try to create a toy example.

Comment: hey you are fitting `model14` but doing `model4.summary()`